# Facebook Dynamic Audiences | Pixel content_ids length

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

Did research on this and spent considerable amount of hours for this but there was no clear conclusion on this.It would be great if someone can guide me on.

Under **`facebook dynamic audiences`**, ***content_ids*** must be submitted for pixel events. In that case, it says the **`recommendation for product item count is 5-10.`**

What if it is required to assign the pixel event for like **`100 products`** items. According to the above statement,

**`will it be inefficient`** to submit such amount of items ?

What are the **`drawbacks`** ?

Thank you

Comment: What events are we talking about here? Other than purchase, I can not even see this making much sense ... in what situation would I as a website visitor do anything with a 100 products at once? View them at once? Then I’d say that rather smells like a badly organized website, if it shows me a 100 products at once, and considers this a “view” of those 100 products at the same time.

Comment: oops. seems like i misunderstood the whole theory here. gotta do more reseach on this, thank you very for the help. thing is, couldnt find any clear documentation regarding this yet